# An algorithm to go from a list of rectangles to a list of sides of the bigger shape

Tags: algorithm

I am searching for an algorithm that can take me from an array of rectangles, each with perfectally straight edges (none are rotated), to another array of edges of the bigger shape.

The rectangles can not overlap, and the all connect.

For example, say you had these two rectangles:

[image: Two rectangles]

Then the result would be 8 edges:

[image: Eight edges]

How can I go about doing this?

Comment: Can these rects overlap or be disconnected?

Comment: No. They all connect and don't overlap.

Comment: How is your array of rectangles modelled in your code ?   Are we dealing with vectors, rasters, or what ?  And how many basic rectangles might there be in a typical run of the program ?  1, 10, 100, 10^8 ?

Comment: I was thinking up to 10 rectangles. They are modeled with their four corners, each corner being an x and y coordinate. In reality, only two corners are even necessary to describe the rectangle.

Comment: You might want to search for a *concave hull* algorithm, but for only 10 rectangles even an `O(n^3)` hand-rolled lash-up is going to be plenty fast enough in practice.  Pick a point (any point), is it on a corner (are there points on the same vertical or horizontal line ?), where's the next nearest point on a straight line (search N, S, E, W), add a boundary line as you walk to that point, carry on until you get back to where you started from.